# Is there anyway I can set the working directory in airflow where my codes will run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I am trying to help my team of data scientist run their code using airflow. 
The problem i faced is that their python scripts will read/write some intermediate files.

1) Is there anyway to set the working directory where their scripts and files can exist so that it will not clutter the dags folder?

2) even if i use the dag folder, I would have to specify the absolute path everytime i read/write those files. unless there is some other way around this?

i.e. i would have to do this all the time:-

```
absolute_path="/some/long/directory/path"    
f = os.path.join(absolute_path,file_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the os module to do this. if you put something like this section of code at the top of your dag file:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/lnx/test/')
```

it will change the working directory for all tasks running in the dag to `/home/lnx/test` so you wouldn't have to provide absolute paths. It will however need to be included at the top of every dag that requires this working directory.

Although this will be a late answer hopefully it can help someone else in this position.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is have a separate folder with all the modules needed to be run and I add that to the airflow run environment.

`PATH_MODULES = "/home/airflow-worker-1/airflow_modules/"`

`sys.path += [ PATH_MODULES ]`

This way, I can import any functions in those folders ( provided that they have `__init__.py` because they are treated as packages.

```
airflow_modules
    |_ code_repository_1
    |_ code_repository_2
    |_ code_repository_3
       |_ file_1.py
       |_ config.py
```

So in your DAG code you use:

```
from code_repository_1.data_cleaning       import clean_1
from code_repository_2.bigquery_operations import operation_1
```

One thing to keep in mind is that since this is treating the repositories as projects so if you need `file_1.py` to import a variable from `config.py`, then you can have to use the relative import with `from .config import variable_1`.

Comment: Python codes are still bearable, I’m more concerned about the data files. For example if i have a whole folder of 100 csv files to read, I would have to append the full path every time i read/write to those files

Comment: No you'll definitely have to specify full paths, you can use environment variables in each machine and have the first part of the path ( `/home/computer` ) appended to the repository paths. You will have to specify full absolute paths though, it makes it a lot easier to debug too.

Comment: I fear as much... I am too, using environemnt variables to append each path in file names. I just wonder if there's a cleaner solution. Thanks @Meghdeep Ray

Comment: It is odd, that one cant just add additional folders in the config-file